# AngularJS promises and nested controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, controller, angular-promise

I have the following dilemma:

If I have two nested controllers like this:

```
Controller1
   Controller2
```

In the Controller1 I have a field

```
someDataService.getMyUser().then(function(user){      
   $scope.user = user;
}
```

which is the result of a promise (an async call to external server). 
So far, so good. But how can I manage the following situation:

I need to use in the Controller2

```
var userName = $scope.$parent.user.userName
```

right when the controller is fired. 
How can I set the second controller, to wait for the promise in the first controller to be resolve, and only then evaluate that var userName assignment? 
(otherwise I would get that $scope.$parent is undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling $scope.$parent.user.userName, can't you call a function (something like $scope.$parent.get_user()) that calls someDataServive.getMyUser() and returns a promise?

Or, isn't better to inject someDataService into Controller2 and call directly the getMyUser() function?

Comment: Making a getter seems to be the solution, I will try it now. I can't simply inject someDataService, because I want to use the second controller in multiple pages, where the parent controller isn't always the same, and thus doesn't always have that someDataService..

Answer (score 0):

It's not really good to have a dependency like this, but if you need to call some init code in Controller2, you can do it using $broadcast to run init code of Controller2 directly from Controller1 when the object will be loaded.